# How to create the XDocument instance for loading the XML file after deserializing the the object?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, deserialization

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the window phone 7 application. I am referring to the following link for XML Serialization & Deserialization.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/wp7rssreader.aspx

In the above link the LoadFromIso() function is used for XML Deserialization. I want to load the xml file after deserialization in the above link. In simple one case we can do this as in the following code. Similar to the following code I want "doc" in the above link. In the following code we can perform the various opeations on the XML file by using LINQ to XML with following statement

```
doc = XDocument.Load(isfStream);
```

The complete code is as follows

```
IsolatedStorageFile isfData = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            XDocument doc = null;
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream = null;
            if (isfData.FileExists(strXMLFile))
            {
                isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strXMLFile, FileMode.Open, isfData);
                doc = XDocument.Load(isfStream);                
                isfStream.Close();
            }
```

In the similar way I want the instance of the XDocument after deserializing the object so that I can perform the various operations on the XML file by using LINQ to XML. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can obtain the instance of the XDocument so that I can load the XML file &  perform the various operation on the XML file by using the LINQ to XML ?

Comment: You have "doc" and it is very unusual to operate on an XML that is used to deserialize. So, I still don't understand the question.

Comment: I agree with Henk.  Your question makes little sense, you already have an instance of XDocument in doc.  So why would you need "any code or link through which I can obtain and instance of the XDocument"?  Or are you just missing a "return doc;"  ???

Comment: I want "doc" in the link - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/wp7rssreader.aspx which I have provided in my question & not in the code which I have provided in my question.

Comment: Can I use "doc" in the link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/wp7rssreader.aspx with the similar way as the code provided in my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `doc` in your code is an XDocument of the deserialized content.
You can perform your operations on/with doc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple WP7 project demonstrating loading XML using XDocument and LINQ and data binding to a listbox here. As Matt advises the work gets done on your XDocument instance.

[binding a Linq datasource to a listbox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/0baf666f-5797-4917-9228-0a66dead8f72)